# Confusion with Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If a system spontaneously expands it should also increase in entropy by the second law of Thermodynamics. But we know that gases cool when they expand, not heat up. How can $CdT$ be negative and $TdS$ be positive?? Isn't
$$dQ = C dT = TdS$$
Does the answer have to do with reversibility? Is $dS$ not always equal to $dQ/T$? Or is $CdT$ actually $dE$ and not $dQ$? Or both?

Comment: Ideal gas: $dE=0 \iff dT=0$.

Comment: @valerio I agree with you, and am therefore even more confused. We know gases cool when they expand. How do you reconcile these two facts?

Comment: $dT=0$: if it's a free expansion (of an ideal gas) we're talking about, the temperature is constant. Therefore, no cooling (nor heating) takes place.

Comment: In real life, gases cool when they expand. Maybe $p$ is not zero. Please explain what you are saying.

Comment: In real life, gases aren't strictly ideal. Further, note that the Joule-Thomson coefficient of various gases can be positive or negative.

Comment: @EricDavidKramer Gases do not have to “heat up” in order for entropy to be generated. While not exactly a “spontaneous” expansion, an example is a non quasi-static  (irreversible) adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas.  The temperature of the gas drops, entropy is generated, but no heat transfer occurs. In this case, $dU$ is not zero. Instead, $dU=-pdV$. Since the expansion is non quasi-static, the pressure in this case is the external pressure and not the gas pressure. The entropy generated can be calculated by reversibly returning the system to its original state.

Comment: Do you know how to determine the change in entropy of a system that experiences an irreversible process such as spontaneous expansion?  If not, here is a step-by-step primer on how to do it, including worked examples:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Comment: If the gas expands spontaneously, there is viscous heating of the gas which partially or completely cancels out the expansion cooling.  So the net effect can indeed be no change in temperature.  However, the volume of the gas has increased, which corresponds to an increase in entropy (increase in the number of quantum mechanical energy states).

Comment: Doesn't $C\text d T=\text dQ$ only hold got constant volume systems?

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, if C = Cv.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes exactly. So isn't then an issue with what the OP is assuming?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens There are numerous issues with what the OP is assuming.  He seems to have no idea how to determine the change in entropy for a gas that has experienced an irreversible process.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yeah this is true...

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't be asking the question. I really like this forum because it has knowledgeable people, it has interesting questions, and it's a great place to get answers that are hard to find in textbooks or papers. On the other hand, a general problem with this and other forums is that most questions seem to have been previously answered, either here or somewhere else on the internet. I think it's a serious problem. Anyway, thank you for the link.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I really like granpa chets entropy recipe. Would it be ok if I reference it in my answers, where appropriate?

Comment: @BobD Of course.  That was my whole motivation for writing it.  I'm hoping it will be widely disseminated so that as many people as possible can benefit from it.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Great, will do. Although I knew how to calculate the change in entropy, I benefited from its step by step systematic approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about a gas expanding you need to be clear about how exactly the gas is expanding. In general the expansion could be complicated, but lets consider three simple examples:

1. reversible isothermal expansion
2. reversible adiabatic expansion
3. Joule expansion i.e. irreversible adiabatic expansion.

As you say the entropy change is related to the heat transferred and the temperature, but you need to be clear about the exact relationship. For a **reversible** process it is:

$$ dS = \frac{dQ_{rev}}{T} \tag{1} $$

But for an irreversible process this becomes:

$$ dS \ge \frac{dQ}{T} \tag{2} $$

It is very important to remember that equation (1) only applies to reversible processes and not to irreversible ones. This is a common confusion for students. In the light of this let's look at the three processes I mentioned about.

For (1) the expanding gas does work on its surroundings and absorbs some heat $\Delta Q$ to maintain its temperature. The entropy change of the gas will be positive and since this is a reversible process the entropy increase is given by $\Delta S = \Delta Q/T$.

For (2) the expanding gas does work on its surroundings and since it absorbs no heat from its surroundings the gas temperature falls. Since this is also a reversible process the entropy increase is given by $\Delta S = \Delta Q/T$ and that means the entropy change for this process is zero.

For (3) in a [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion) the gas is expanding into a vacuum so it does no work and exchanges no energy with its surroundings. That means its internal energy doesn't change so its temperature doesn't change. In this process $\Delta Q=0$, but equation (1) does not apply because this is not a reversible process. We have to use equation (2), and that means the entropy change does not have to be zero. In fact as the Wikipedia article explains the molar entropy increase is greater than zero and is given by:

$$ \Delta S = R \ln\left(\frac{V_f}{V_i}\right) $$

So the point is that in an expansion the gas temperature may or may not fall, and the entropy may or may not change. What happens depends on exactly how you do the expansion.

Comment: Another common confusion of students regards the temperature T in Eqn. 2.  In this Clausius inequality, the T is supposed to be temperature at the boundary between the system and surroundings (where the heat transfer is taking place), not the average temperature of the system.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suppose I'm also confused about what makes a process reversible or not. Can't I always adjust the volume with a piston, and adjust the temperature using a heat bath?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer strictly speaking properties like temperature and pressure are only defined for a gas that is in equilibrium, and a gas is in equilibrium only if it is not changing. So we get the somewhat awkward situation that we can't describe any change in a gas because if the gas is changing it's not in equilibrium and therefore temperature and pressure aren't defined. In practice temperature and pressure are well enough defined to be useful if the change is slow compared to rate at which the gas equilibrates, and this is where we get the idea of a reversible process.

Comment: A reversible process is one that is sufficiently slow that the gas is effectively in equilibrium throughout the process.

Comment: @Rennie Thank you! So an adiabatic expansion can also be reversible in an insulated piston?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer yes. But note that both the Joule expansion and a reversible adiabatic expansion are both adiabatic. The difference is that the Joule expansion is very rapid while an expansion with a piston can be one as slowly as necessary to keep it reversible.

Comment: So entropy can be generated 1) whenever there is heat transfer, or 2) when the process happens out of equilibrium?

Answer (score 4):

The spontaneous expansion of an isolated gas system does not necessarily mean the gas will cool down (decrease in temperature). The classic example is a Joule expansion.

Consider a rigid insulated chamber is partitioned into two equal parts. Half the chamber contains an ideal gas. The other half is a vacuum. The system is isolated since there can be no heat or mass transfer and no boundary work (rigid walls).

An opening is created in the partition allowing the gas to freely expand into the evacuated half. Since the chamber is insulated, there is no heat transfer ($Q=0$). Since the expansion of the gas does not expand the boundaries of the chamber, there is no boundary work ($W=0$). Consequently, per the first law, the change in internal energy is zero ($\Delta U=0$). Being an ideal gas, where a change in internal energy depends only on a change in temperature, there is therefore no change in temperature.

The end result is the volume has doubled the pressure has halved and the temperature is unchanged.

Although no heat transfer has occurred, the process is obviously irreversible (you would not expect the gas to spontaneously return to its original half of the chamber).  But we can determine the entropy generated by taking any convenient reversible process to return the gas to its initial conditions. The obvious choice here is to remove the insulation and perform a reversible isothermal compression. To do that requires heat transfer to the surroundings.  That amount of heat represents “lost work”, that is, the work that could have been done if the free expansion of the gas was replaced by a reversible adiabatic expansion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm willing to believe that there are ways to let gas expand that do not change its temperature.  But suppose you have compressed gas in an insulated piston that is expanding against atmospheric pressure. Here the gas will cool. Shouldn't the entropy be positive by the second law?

Comment: @EricDavidKramer My answer was based on you referring to an "isolated system". The system you are describing in the comment is not isolated but adiabatic, since it is doing work on the surroundings. In thermodynamics the definition of an isolated system is one that does not transfer heat, work, or mass with its surroundings. You may want to edit your question.